Why is there a "false" in the output of `helm upgrade`
When I ran helm upgrade to update my chart, there is a "false" in the output though the upgrade completed successfully with revision increased:
user@vhkgpf88 (qa) loki_chart]$ helm upgrade loki . -n logging
**false** <----------------------- this is the "false"
Release "loki" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
NAME: loki
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Apr 26 13:38:10 2024
NAMESPACE: logging
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 3
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
Welcome using Our Logging solution!

Did I mis-configure something?
K8S version: 1.25 (openshift 4.12.0)
Helm version: 3.13.0

You've already raised an issue, what did you expect anyone here to do about it?

Well, just in case anyone met this issue before here in stack, I think this might be a bug but some mis-config

I have the exact same question.
More specifically I am using helm upgrade --install which can be used for 2 cases:

To perform a clean installation or
To perform an update of an already installed helm chart.

I did a little bit of research but I did not find anything..
I am not 100% sure but I think that the boolean value returned is to indicate if the actual action performed from the command is a clean "first" installation or if the actual action is an update. .
Also I found this github issue which kind of verify my assumption. I wish the output of the command was more descriptive
